# Android Backup service delay

Tags: android, android-backup-service

I'm using the Android Backup Service in my current app. 
I've read on the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html#BackupAgentHelper) that

> A backup request does not result in an immediate call to your onBackup() method. Instead, the Backup Manager waits for an appropriate time, then performs backup for all applications that have requested a backup since the last backup was performed.

Does anyone know approximately how long can it take from the `dataChanged()` request to actual backup operation?

Or maybe it would be a good option to ditch the Android backup service altogether and select other storage?

Best regards!

Comment: Android backup is not the right tool to sync your data. As far as I know the data backup happen once a day and only in some predefined circumstances like "on wifi", "battery is charged" and others.

Comment: I don't know that for sure, it was the answer from GDE on the conference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then what is suited for? The name suggests that I can use it to store e.g. user preferences in there and when the user reinstalls the data or wipes the app it should restore them to the previous state. But in the case as you described, it doesn't look as though i could use it any for that purpose.

Comment: You're right, it suppose to back up your data - db, shared prefs, some other files in data folder. But the limit is 25 Mb, when you hit the limit backup would be auto-disabled. Now OS decides when to do backUp and normally it's ok to backup once per day.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have finally moved the backup to google drive appfolder (I was using drive already in the app, so it wasn't much of a problem). It's a pity though that the backup works that way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact time from calling dataChanged() to the data actually being pushed to the backup storage backend will vary based on several factors: connectivity, principally.  The version of Android that the device is running matters too; the delay policy has been tweaked over the years.  The reason there's a delay at all is to avoid pushing a lot of data "unnecessarily," using up peoples' monthly data quota, while still trying to keep the backend at least mostly up to date, so that you don't lose tons of changes if you accidentally drop the phone in a river or something.  Typically the latency is up to an hour, though as of Android M it's rather longer (more like 4 hours).  For testing purposes you can always force an immediate backup pass with this adb command:

```
adb shell bmgr run
```

You can also simulate your app's calling dataChanged() first with a different call to the **bmgr** shell tool:

```
adb shell bmgr backup com.myapps.packagename
```

(only using whatever your app's package name really is, of course.)

You don't say which data path your app is using -- full data (new in Android M) or key/value (introduced in Android Froyo).  dataChanged() is only relevant for the older key/value API.

As Viktor Yakunin above pointed out, backup is not sync: the goal of the backup system is to deliver the app's data seamlessly when the app is installed, either on a new device that the user is setting up, or following uninstall and reinstall of the app on the same device.  If what you want is a data *exchange* mechanism, or maintaining identical data simultaneously across multiple devices, you should look at the Sync Manager or other similar 3rd party facilities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Appreciate the detailed explanation :) I wanted it to store user's data across reinstalls / data clearing, but the delay was too long for my use case. But it was nice experience though :)

Comment: You can't store data across a "clear data" operation with this mechanism. When the user clears data on the app, the backup system will then obligingly back up the new state, i.e. the state without any data.  It *will* handle the uninstall/reinstall case, but not on a short time horizon: if the user uninstalls the app within a few hours (or a day) then the data will not necessarily have been backed up -- but in that case, the user has basically said they aren't interested in the app in the first place.

Comment: Oh, good to know that. Thanks :-) I thought that if the user clears the data on the phone, it will be restored later on.

Comment: Yup -- the fundamental model is that it's maintaining a mirror of the device's data-state in the backup. There's latency because we don't want to grind away your monthly data cap pushing data to backup immediately when anything changes, but the "steady state" when things catch up (typically overnight) is that the backup has been brought up to date to match whatever is on device.